# I can't seem to get started with Zend Framework 2 skeleton app

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

I'm following through the getting started skeleton app tutorial on the Zend homepage:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

I've got as far as being able to enter into the browser address bar "zf2-tutorial.localhost/" and my Zend welcome page should appear. It doesn't, the apache web folder (/var/www) directory appears instead. If I enter "http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/1234" to test whether the Zend 404 page appears, it doesn't. The default apache Not Found page appears.

I created my app by running in terminal:

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://packages.zendframework.com" zendframework/skeleton-application:dev-master /var/www/zf2-tutorial
```

.. this created all the files in the desired folder (/var/www/zf2-tutorial).

I then created the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/zf2-tutorial` with the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/zf2-tutorial/public
         SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
         <Directory /var/www/zf2-tutorial/public>
                 DirectoryIndex index.php
                 AllowOverride All 
                 Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
         </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I updated my `/etc/hosts` file with:

```
127.0.0.1               zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
```

I restarted apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

.. and by this point I should be able to see the Zend welcome page so I can proceed with the rest of the tutorial but nothing.

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu) and PHP 5.5.14.

Is there anything obvious that I've missed out? I've got a feeling that it has something to do with the mod_rewrites but I'm a little confused which I should be updated and how. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [... same code ....]
</VirtualHost>
```

in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file and restart the `apache2`

---

**Update -**

If it still doesn't work then try the below command and check -

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

This will enable the `rewrite` module if not already is.

**After entering the URL in the browser, if the required page is not displayed then check the apache error log file located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`**

By this, you could get some idea as where its going wrong.

Comment: Tried, no joy. Seems earlier I'd forgotten to use a2ensite when it was a separate file  and also had to change the zf2-tutorial file to zf2-tutorial.conf file. That didn't help either. Looking at the HTTP request header also I can confirm that there is a "Host  zf2-tutorial.localhost", apache should pick on this no?

Comment: Please check the `Update` added to the above answer. Please let us know the result.

Comment: Damn. It works now. I tried your initial suggestion again, and it worked. So, I took the zf2-tutoril VirtualHost out of 000-default.conf and put it back into zf2-tutorial.conf, enabled it and restarted apache. Now it works, I don't know why. I guess that I wasn't enabling sites properly. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was in config file name. In directory **sites-enabled** files should have **.conf** in the end of name.

- Good: **zf2-tutorial.conf**
- Bad: **zf2-tutorial**